# Why Is Java Program Not Recognizing Second Command Line Argument?

Tags: java

Building a Random Number Generator that takes a upper boundary input, and numbers to be generated by the user and prints the results.

For whatever reason my program (which compiles), doesn't recognize the boundary argument as the second argument and exits per my checking of arguments.

Any help would be appreciated in my understanding of how to fix this and what I may be missing.

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandNumGen{
    public static void main(String[] args){

// intro
System.out.println("*****************************************");
System.out.println("*Welcome to the Random Number Generator!*");
System.out.println("*    Discussion 7: Michael Stadnicki    *");
System.out.println("*****************************************");

// ask user to input numbers to be generated
System.out.println("Please enter how many random numbers you would like generated!");
Scanner numGen = new Scanner(System.in);
    int randomNum = numGen.nextInt();
System.out.println("We will generate " + randomNum +" random numbers!");

// ask user to input out boundary for the random numbers
System.out.println("Please enter the boundary for our random numbers to be generated!");
Scanner boundGen = new Scanner(System.in);
    int randomBound = boundGen.nextInt();
System.out.println("We will use " + randomBound +" as our boundary for generation!");

// build our random number generator
Random rNum = new Random();

// check our arguments
if (args.length == 2) {
    randomNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    randomBound = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
} else {
    System.out.println("You are required to have 2 arguments on the command line!");
    System.exit(0);
}

// print our random numbers generated based on above bounds and numbers
for (int i = 0; i <randomNum; i++) {
    int numOutput = rNum.nextInt(randomBound + 1);
    System.out.println("Your random numbers are: " + numOutput);
}

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you asking for both user input and command line arguments...?

Comment: And hint: you could print that args array to see what it contains. Learning to program is about making experiments yourself...

Comment: My guess is that you aren't actually passing command line arguments like `java myProgram <arg 1> <arg 2>`. Do not get a `Scanner` reading system input confused with command line arguments, they are totally separate!

Comment: I see, so looking at this article: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/cmdLineArgs/index.html  I could use two int variables such as lets say int numbers = 0; and int boundValue = 0; and then work to pass those down rather than using inputs through the scanner class?

Answer (score 0):

Try only asking for user imput, don't use args. And don't use two different scanners, just call
   numGen.nextInt(); 
two times.